# How to allow horizontal overflow in CSS?

Tags: css, scroll, alignment

I built a rather minimal personal webpage for design work and want each project to be shown as a long horizontal scroll. I'd been controlling the width of each page by pixel and it works for browsers, but I noticed that when I open the page on my phone, the last image always jumps to the next line. I am wondering how to compensate for this, if there is an easy fix.

Sample link : http://gh-he.com/Projects/Sutro.html

If you open with browser, probably fine. Open with phone, it jumps. I am by no means a programmer so sort of fumbled my way through to what I got, the code is probably quite messy compared to what you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `overflow-x`  property to `scroll` on the container of the images.

```
.images-container{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

If you want your text to stay in place and only have the images that scroll, put the `img`  in a container and set the `overflow-x`  property on that images container only.